# Hiding libs packages to implementators

Tags: java, package, visibility

Am writing a lib where I have a package with several classes inside, one of this classes is the final class  **Point**( that is used by many other classes but has no public access outside its package
in this case **com.ve.free**)

now when I import the final jar, I realised that if a developer using my lib creates a package **com.ve.free** in its project aswell, then he can 
use my class Point  too...

I think this is a vulnerability  in my code, but how can I avoid that?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not a problem. Visibiliti modifiers are protect us from unintended errors. If someone intentionally want to break rules it is not much can be done.

But if you really want what you asked you can design your library to work with custom class loader. All your secret class should be loaded in this custom class loader. It will not protect you from `reflection` unfortunately.

But you should think twise is the profit more than costs?